# Python CSV reader prints column instead of row

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a dataset that i saved as a csv in Sublime after pasting from excel

When I call csv.reader to print all the rows, the whole set is printed out (fantastic):

**Output 1**

[image: Output # 1]

Now that I want to call to print the first row of my dataset "print(row[0])", the first entire column of my dataset prints out:

**Output 2**
[image: Output # 2]

PLEASE HELP! I am trying to learn python.

Comment: Please include code instead of images of your code:  this is really difficult to read

Answer (score 1):

`row` is a row.  `row[0]` is the first element of that row.

If you want to just print the first row, do `print(row)` then `break` to stop the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use such code:

```
import csv
with open("exampleSet.csv") as productivityCost:
   readPC = csv.reader(productivityCost, delimeter = ",")
   print(row[0])
```